# How to have a progress bar with uploading a file in Django 3.0.4

Tags: django, file, upload

This can easily be done with Ajax and Jquery, but this version of Django seems to be making it extra difficult. It requires the '{% csrf_token %}' (it'll throw an error without this) and that automatically submits the file when submit is pressed.

```
<form
  id="data_upload"
  method="POST"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  class="form-horizontal"
>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="custom-file">
      <input
        id="file_select"
        type="file"
        class="custom-file-input"
        id="inputGroupFile02"
        accept=".csv, .xslx"
        name="file"
      />
      <label
        id="submit_label"
        class="custom-file-label"
        for="inputGroupFile02"
        aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon02"
        >Upload CSV or Excel file</label
      >
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button
        id="upload_button"
        type="submit"
        class="input-group-text btn"
        id="inputGroupFileAddon02"
        disabled
      >
        Upload
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div
      id="loading_div"
      class="spinner-border"
      role="status"
      style="display: none;"
    >
      <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's the ajax

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#data_upload").submit(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var fd = new FormData
      fd.append('file', file_input[0].files[0])

      $.ajax({
        xhr: function () {
          var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest()

          xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
          xhr.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
          xhr.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
          xhr.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);

          return xhr;
        },
        url: window.location.href,
        type: "POST",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (result) {
          alert('WOOOO!')
        },
      });
    });
  });
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('upload', UploadView.as_view(), name="upload"),
]
```

View.py

```
class UploadView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'upload_datatable.html')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
        uploaded_file_name = uploaded_file.name

        if len(uploaded_file) != 0:
            if uploaded_file_name.endswith('.csv'):
                file_path = self.upload_csv_to_data(uploaded_file)
            elif uploaded_file_name.endswith('xlsx'):
                file_path = self.upload_excel(uploaded_file)
            else:
                return HttpResponse({'error': 'Not valid CSV or Excel'}, content_type="application/json",
                                    status_code=400)
        else:
            return HttpResponse({'error': 'No Data'}, content_type="application/json", status_code=400)

    def upload_csv_to_data(self, file):
        id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        with open(f'data/{id}.csv', 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)

        return f'data/{id}'

    def upload_excel_to_data(self, file):
        id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        with open(f'data/{id}.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)

        return f'data/{id}'

    def is_csv_file(self, file):
        try:
            dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(file.read(1024))
            file.seek(0)

            return True
        except csv.Error:
            return False

    def is_excel_file(self, file):
        try:
            book = open_workbook(file)

            return True
        except XLRDError as e:
            return False
```

So when I have preventDefault to stop Django from sending anything, but when I look at network, nothing is being sent and the "WOOOOO!" isn't being printed and my breakpoint in Django at the POST endpoint isn't be triggered. So I don't think the ajax is sending the file, but at the same time I'm getting no errors. Any advice?

Comment: Can you please share the ajax code also

Comment: added ajax code

Comment: Well, you *are* uploading the document twice. How about not actually doing so in the /upload POST method but only via the ajax code? Then check the status of the upload in the /upload method and process the file once the ajax upload is finished.

Comment: @rolando. So are you suggesting removing POST from the html and just handle it with the jquery?

Comment: Or discarding the upload data in the POST method right away as the upload is handled by ajax. Not using POST at all seems dirty as you *are* changing the app's state.

Comment: Will the progress actually track the Django file upload then? I assumed it's linked to the upload data in the POST method

Comment: @rolando well I got a new issue if you want to look at the new code

Comment: Your `url` parameter looks interesting. This should include your API endpoint and not just the browsers location bar content. It might possibly help to make sure you have your backend API up and running correctly (either writing tests for it or using tools like Postman). Then add the client's ajax calls.

Comment: @rolando I made the post endpoint being this current url, so that should be fine?

Comment: Well, usually an API endpoint is something along the line of `/api/fancymethod` and thus doesn't involve all the protocol and hostname and port and the like. While you can surely make your approach with `window.location.href` work, it just seems more complicated than necessary. I would heavily suggest to make the simple API work first and adding the ajax call second.

Comment: @rolando the API works, it worked when Django made the post, just now it doesn't work with Ajax for some reason. I should check what window.location.href is though to make sure it is indeed posting to the correct URL.

Comment: @user8714896 I added an answer, but can you post your views.py and urls.py as well so I can see if there's anything your API requires for your AJAX to work

Comment: added to the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though no error was thrown when I removed

```
    xhr: function () {
      var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest()

      xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
      xhr.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
      xhr.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
      xhr.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);

      return xhr;
    },
```

it started to work so yea.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `e.currentTarget` when instantiating a new `FormData` object so you include the `csrf_token` in the submitted info.

```
...
var fd = new FormData(event.currentTarget)
fd.append('file', file_input[0].files[0])
...
```

Comment: That's great advice. Unfortunately I tried it and still nothing happened. I'm sure that helps me solve part of the problem though. I checked my network tab in chrome dev tools and it said nothing was sent so I'm not sure what is going on. And no errors are being consoled out either.

Comment: Have you confirmed the listener is being fired in the first place?

Comment: I was able to figure it out, the xhr was creating an error that wasn't being thrown.